# Solidity event not showing up from Web3.js

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js

I'm trying to set up an event in Solidity and listen to it from Web3js but I keep getting a `null` response. Here's my code:

The relevant part of the contract:

```
event NewUser(string userid);

function createNewUser(string memory _userId) public {
    // creating the user and setting it to a mapping 
    emit NewUser(_userId);
}
```

The JavaScript, from Ethereum's reference:

```
async function watchEvents(contract) {
    contract.events.allEvents({
       fromBlock: 0
    },function(error, event){ console.log('all events?'); console.log(event); })
  .on('data', function(event){
     console.log(event); // same results as the optional callback above
  })
  .on('changed', function(event){
     // remove event from local database
  })
  .on('error', console.error);
}
```

Using another JavaScript function I can see that new users are being created, and the transactions are listed as successful on Ganache. But the `watchEvents` method keeps printing `null`.

What am I missing?

Comment: what's you Ethereum provider? infura or own node?

Comment: @YegorZaremba I'm using my own node. Someone on another thread told me the reason for the `null` is that events are only supported by a `websockets` provider. I haven't tested it yet.

Answer (score 1):

Please connect to a websocket provider to enable listen for events. To run a websocket provider, run the node with the following flags:

```
--ws --wsport XXXX --wsorigins="*"
```

Please note that for security reasons you most likely do **NOT** want to allow ***** but instead be more explicit.

Then connect to it by something like:

```js
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider("ws://localhost:XXXX"))
```